# Missing features of eclipse PDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde

After I used the PDE for some time now I cannot do any actions of it anymore, e.g. does the plugin project group does not appear anymore at "New". Updating and reinstalling did not help. Google research did no give any results out. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: If it is also not in _File > New > Other..._, you have installed the wrong Eclipse IDE package.

Comment: This makes sense, because I am using the Mars.2 package and the PDE says Luna, but it is the only one that comes up if I type in PDE in the Eclipse Marketplace. It also is weird because I used it before and it worked just fine.

Comment: You install major features like PDE through Help > Install New Software and choose your main release site.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes I know. It is already installed. I have used it before and it worked. But now it just does not anymore and I am kinda desperate bc I don´t know why.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling eclipse and then installing PDE again worked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue, you have to delete Eclipse than reinstall as stated above.

If you updated the eclipse instance, that could be the issue. I have noticed that when Eclipse is updated, but the runtime instance of eclipse is not, PDE tends to break. Try deleting the runtime instance, after copying your files over to a temp directory, anytime after you update. A new Eclipse runtime directory will be produced matching the current Eclipse version. This should help prevent any future errors.